# Local Git Config have always unwanted filemode settings after git clone

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, config

When I clone a repository from bitbucket, my local git config in the repository-clone have always some settings, who are not match my global settings.

I want filemode = false. But in the local git config it's always set true by default after a git clone.

I am wondering where this local git settings come from and how I can edit this "skeleton".

Comment: Do you mean `core.filemode`?

Comment: yes, exactly. I mean `core.filemode`. I have core.filemode in my global git config set tofalse, but in my local config after a clone its set to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These `core` settings:

- `core.bare`
- `core.repositoryformatversion`
- `core.ignorecase`
- `core.filemode`

are not settings that *you* should normally change.  The first two are Git's own internal settings, and the remaining two inform Git about the *behavior of your operating system* when used on the repository Git has just created.

Specifically, `core.filemode` tells Git the result of the following experiment:<sup>1</sup>

- Create a new file with mode read/write only (no execute).

  Now set the execute bit.  Is the execute bit set?

  Now clear the execute bit.  Is the execute bit cleared?

If the execute bit follows the commands to set and clear it, `core.filemode` is set to `true`.  This tells Git that both you and Git can control whether the execute bit is set or not.

The `core.ignorecase` setting is established at the time a new repository is created through a simpler experiment:

- Create the `.git/config` file.  Now try to read a file named `.git/CoNfIg`.  Is this possible?

If so, the operating system will open a file whose file name differs only in case from the actual file.  Git records this information in `core.ignorecase`.

(The `repositoryformatversion` is set to the compiled-in constant zero, or sometimes adjusted to 1 if you make use of some new features.  Should repository formats change in the future, Git will set the format version in new repositories to the appropriate number.  The `bare` flag is set based on whether you created a bare clone, perhaps with `--bare` or perhaps with `--mirror`.)

Because `core.ignorecase` and `core.filemode` are not *intended* to be user-configurable, Git offers no way to set them to something other than what Git is hardcoded to do based on your operating system.  It's a bit dangerous to change them, as they inform Git *how the system behaves*, and Git may depend on that behavior for correct operation of various Git commands.  However, it is possible to lie with either or both of them for certain special effects.  Just be sure that you know what you are doing, when you do that.

(Setting `core.filemode` to `false`, even if Git would have set it to `true`, is currently "safe", for some definition of safe, at all times, so if it gives you the behavior you want, that's actually OK, at least for now.  Neither I nor Git make any promises about future versions of Git here.)

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a compile-time option for Git to tell it: *Do not run the experiment; just set `core.filemode` to false every time.*  So for your particular purposes, you could obtain a copy of the Git source and rebuild it with `NO_TRUSTABLE_FILEMODE` set.  But it may be easier to just make an alias or shell script that you use instead of `git init` or `git clone`, that does the init-or-clone and then changes the setting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the deep detailed explanation!